# 2d Kernal Density plot where points with 0 density are ignored (using ggplot2) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, density-plot

I am attempting to plot a density of shots taken onto a image of a basketball court; however, I am unable to figure out how to make it so the points where density = 0 are ignored.

I am currently getting the following:

[image: Bad_Court]

The code I am using to do so is the following:

```
## LIBRARIES 
library(grid)
library(jpeg)
library(RCurl)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(viridis)

courtImg.URL = "https://thedatagame.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/nba_court.jpg"

court = rasterGrob(readJPEG(getURLContent(courtImg.URL)),
                   width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))


ggplot(df, aes(x = df$Baseline, y=df$Side)) +
     ylim(0, 100) +
     ylab(" ") +
     xlim(-50, 50) +
     xlab("Baseline") +
     annotation_custom(court, -50, 50, 0, 100) +
     coord_fixed() +
     scale_fill_viridis(option='inferno', end=1) +
     stat_density_2d(aes(fill =..density..), geom = "raster", contour=FALSE) +
     guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "% of Shots Taken"))
```

My desired output is something like the following:

[image: Good_Court]

At the end of the day, I'm just trying to make a heatmap version of a shot chart. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I may be able to do this in a totally different way that works, I am absolutely open to it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really simple: the tiles you're placing over the image are opaque, so they make it impossible to see the court. Decrease the alpha, and you can see both the raster and the court drawn below.

```r
library(grid)
library(jpeg)
library(RCurl)

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(viridis)


courtImg.URL = "https://thedatagame.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/nba_court.jpg"

court = rasterGrob(readJPEG(getURLContent(courtImg.URL)),
                                     width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"))

df <- data.frame(Baseline = rnorm(100, 0, 30), Side = rnorm(100, 50, 25))

ggplot(df, aes(x = df$Baseline, y=df$Side)) +
    ylim(0, 100) +
    ylab(" ") +
    xlim(-50, 50) +
    xlab("Baseline") +
    annotation_custom(court, -50, 50, 0, 100) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_fill_viridis(option='inferno', end=1) +
    stat_density_2d(aes(fill =..density..), geom = "raster", contour=F, alpha = 0.5) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "% of Shots Taken"))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).